# can't import icomoon custom font with webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I used icomoon.io to generate a custom font from svgs I uploaded. I downloaded the font folder. I am using a vue cli pre built project.

I tried to access the font like the demo file from the folder I downloaded by referencing style.css in my defaults.scss file in which I import all my style sheets but I get this error:

```
Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                                                                                          19:04:44

These relative modules were not found:

* ./fonts/icomoon.eot?8j65w9 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./n
ode_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ./fonts/icomoon.svg?8j65w9 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./n
ode_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ./fonts/icomoon.ttf?8j65w9 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./n
ode_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ./fonts/icomoon.woff?8j65w9 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./
node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
```

I didn't fiddle much with webpack configuration that were in the vue template.. but here is the rules related to fonts. should I change anything

```
{ test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000,
name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]') } 
}
```

Comment: thanks @TomasBy for your patience. its my first question here :D

Comment: I have the same problem. What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but I solved it by modifying `fonts/` to `../fonts/` in `style.css`

Is your relative path correct?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by creating new file "vue.config.js" and adding content ->

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: `@import "~@/assets/styles/scss/_fonts.scss";`
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then changed url of fonts in _fonts.scss ->

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:  url('~@/assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?5jv8om');
    src:  url('~@/assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?5jv8om#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('~@/assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf?5jv8om') format('truetype'),
      url('~@/assets/fonts/icomoon.woff?5jv8om') format('woff'),
      url('~@/assets/fonts/icomoon.svg?5jv8om#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: block;
  }
```